# For the provided string <a href=“/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018”> how to Create a two variables and pass into next reqst

Tags: jmeter

Assign month as one varaible and year as one variable pass into next requst  For the above thing needed using bean shell post processor  and dummy sampler

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this using scripting the relevant code would be something like:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

String responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("Response Data: " + responseData);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(responseData);

int counter = 1;
while (m.find()){
   log.info("var_"+ counter + "=" + m.group(1));
   vars.put("var_" + counter, m.group(1));
   counter++;
}
```

It will create the following JMeter Variables:

```
var_1=07
var_2=2018
```

You will be able to access them as `${var_1}` and `{var_2}` later on.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Scripting Extract Values Regex]

In the above demo `prev` stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), this way you can have access to the Dummy Sampler response data. [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) are "normal" Java classes.

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language. The main reason is that [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), moreover it is more modern, compliant with latest Java versions and has some nice features on top.

Comment: superbbb Dmitri, u had given me good info, am very thankful to u .....!

Comment: HI Dmitri , <a href=“/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018”> In this string how to Iterate month and year means i.e.if we put like this  <a href=“/statement.php?month=${month}&amp;year=${year}”> can u pls suggest me.

Comment: Given my setup you should use something like `<a href=“/statement.php?month=${var_1}&amp;year=${var_2}”>`, you can check out which JMeter Variables are defined (and see their values) using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination. Refer to [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about troubleshooting your JMeter tests.

Comment: how to assign month and year in the beanshell post processor code.if i add <a href=“/statement.php?month=${month}&amp;year=${year}”> in dummy sampler response.can u pls suggest me @dmitri T

Answer (score 1):

Add a [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child to the first request where you are getting above response

add the following regular expression and template to the regular expression extractor

name : `variable`

Regular Expression :`php\?month=(\d{2})&amp;year=(\d{4})”>`

Template: `$1$2$`

Match no :`1`

as shown below

[image]

Above extractor stores month and year in `variable_g1` `variable_g2`

use `${variable_g1}` to pass month in any subsequent request and `${variable_g2}` to pass year

[image]

Result screenshot
[image]

For more information on regular expression extraction please [follow this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: rohit thats great...! but with beanshell post processor assigned variables need to pass into another reqst like month as one variable and year as another variable